# Convert Minecraft Mod into Server Plugin

Tags: minecraft, bukkit, minecraft-forge

I have developing Forge Minecraft mods for some time now. I was wondering if it were possible to actually put them on a server. I can't seem to find a direct answer. I know that this may not be the place to put this but I am just dying to know. Please let me know if I can do it, and if so, how.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about modding a game and nothing to do with programming at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't turn a MC mod into a server plugin because Bukkit and Forge are different things (take it from a plugin dev); however, you can make a mod work on **Forge** servers.

When making a Forge server, all of your server's players will have to have the client mod, in addition to the Forge client, installed for it to work, so be prepared.

The first step is to actually [install](http://www.akliz.net/manage/knowledgebase/35/How-to-Install-a-Forge-Server.html) the server. Next, go to your Forge server folder, and upload the mod(s) into the folder. Then restart your server and boom, its there. Server mods can be found [here](http://modlist.mcf.li/version/1.8).

So if you didn't want to read this, the gist of it is, **no**, you cannot, **but** your mods can be used on a Forge server, but not as plugins for a Bukkit or Spigot server, and that your players will need a clientside modpack. Hope this helped!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make your mod server side only, without having your "clients" having to download it, add `acceptableRemoteVersions = "*"` to your @Mod line.

This way players don't have to have the mod to be able to connect to the server. This way you can have plugins/mods like dynmap or whotookmycookies without the players having to have the mod as well.

If you want to put them on a server, yes you can. But keep in mind if you solely developped for single player worlds you'll run into "Side" issues.
Code will break beacuse some code is specifically Client side only, and some code is Server side only.

You will have to adapt some synching  code with packets to make sure all your graphical things will happen and user input will be returned to you.

Single player worlds are way less picky in that aspect. So make sure you run all your code on the "proper" side, and remember `if(!world.isRemote)`(test to see if you are running serverside) is your friend.

```
@Mod(modid = MyMod.MODID, name = MyMod.NAME, version = MyMod.VERSION), acceptableRemoteVersions = "*"
public class MyMod {
   ....
}
```